# data collected in different timezone and both need to match to UTC

Tags: r, datetime

I have one variable C in Australian/Brisbane time zone and another variable P in UTC and I need them to match in UTC so that a value of P collected at 10am UTC correspond to a value of C collected at the same time.  Thank you very much

this is my data:

```
  Date  Time.AU    C            Date.UTC Time.UTC        P
1 4/9/16  5:00 pm  12.0008511   4/9/16  2:00 am         17.78006
2 4/9/16  6:00 pm  6.4958920    4/9/16  3:00 am         16.13160
```

and I tried

```
DateTime<-paste(data$Date, data$Time)
DT<-strptime(DateTime,format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")+32400
#32400 is because Australia is 9hrs ahead of UTC and I did 60x60x9
```

I need to shift C 9 hrs behind.

Comment: Some data (add the output of `dput()` to your question in a code block) wld help folks help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using lubridate for this kind of stuff?

```
library(lubridate)
utcExampleDate <- ymd_hms("2016-12-31 17:00:00", 
                          tz = "UTC") # "2016-12-31 17:00:00 UTC"
convertToAU <- with_tz(utcExampleDate, 
                       "Australia/Brisbane") # "2017-01-01 03:00:00 AEST"
```

Comment: Thank you! I used lubridate and now I have both variables in UTC.